# Error Whitelabel Error Page: There was an unexpected error (type = Not Found, status = 404) when querying with mapping over level 1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

Faced an extremely ambiguous and incomprehensible problem in my opinion.
I have an application on Spring Boot + Kotlin. Previously, the application had exceptions for Rest controllers; recently there was a need to give html in responses, and therefore added a regular controller. However, when mapping this controller to more than 1 level - all requests (with more than 1 level) cause an error:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Whitelabel Error Page </h1>
<p> This application has no explicit mapping for / error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. </p>
<div> There was an unexpected error (type = Not Found, status = 404). </div>
<div> No message available </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Moreover, requests at the 1st level work out correctly.

It is completely incomprehensible what this is connected with. A large number of attempts to fix this (nothing helped), but could have missed something.

I apply settings with which I associate possible problems (if suddenly someone tries to help and something else is needed - tell me, I will add this information)

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
class WelcomeEndpoint {

    @GetMapping
    fun welcome(): String {
        return "index.html"
    }

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    fun signIn(): String {
        return "index.html"
    }
}
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final val classpathResourceLocations = arrayOf(
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/"
    )

    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(*classpathResourceLocations)
        }
    }

    override fun addViewControllers(registry: ViewControllerRegistry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html")
    }

    @Bean
    fun internalResourceViewResolver(): ViewResolver {
        val viewResolver = InternalResourceViewResolver()
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView::class.java)
        return viewResolver
    }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class CommonSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    private val permitPatterns = arrayOf(
            "/",
            "/welcome/**",
            "/resources/**",
            "/actuator/health**",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**"
    )

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(*permitPatterns).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/internal/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(filter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }

    // ... some logic after ...
}
```

Thus, if I execute the request along the path `http://localhost:8080/welcome`, I will get the `index.html` page
If I execute the request along the path `http://localhost:8080/welcome/welcome` - I get the error above

The `index.html` file is located on the path `src/main/resources/static/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way Spring is resolving your static page.
Since `"/welcome/welcome"` is nested, you will need to use the correct relative path to your resource or an absolute path.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
class WelcomeEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    fun signIn(): String {
        return "../index.html"
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
class WelcomeEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    fun signIn(): String {
        return "/index.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I tried such options that I didn’t even think about it at all, thank you very much!